# Mozilla browser bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox

I am trying to create a game using javascript but along the way I found a bug in firefox. The game is simple. You should guess what color is in the RGB hexacode. There are 6 boxes, You should click the box and it will alert if its wrong or correct. The game is working fine in chrome,IE,Opera while it does not work in mozilla firefox. I did an alert to debug it and firefox add some inline style with it. Please see the screen shot below and code. Hopefully you can help me how to fix this issue in firefox. Thanks in advance

[FIREFOX SCREENSHOT PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh1jy.jpg) 
[CHROME SCREENSHOT NO PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io2ig.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Color Game</title>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  background-color: #232323;
 }

 h1 {
  color:#fff;
 }
 .square {
  width: 30%;
  background: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
 }

 #container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Guess what color is<span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span>
<br/>
Click the box to know what color it is.
</h1>

<div id="container">
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var colors = [
 "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
 "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
 "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
 "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
 ];

 var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
 var pickedColor = colors[1];
 var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

 colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

 for (var i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
  //add initial colors to square
  squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
  //add click listener to square
  squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
   var clickedColor = this.style.background;
   alert(clickedColor);
   if (clickedColor === pickedColor){
    alert("Correct");
   } else{
    alert("Wrong");
   }
  });
 }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `backgroundColor` property instead of [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) shorthand:

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
    ];

    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
    var pickedColor = colors[1];
    var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

    for (var i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
        //add initial colors to square
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
        //add click listener to square
        squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
            alert(clickedColor);
            if (clickedColor === pickedColor){
                alert("Correct");
            } else{
                alert("Wrong");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a Firefox bug. You should specify `backgroundColor`, otherwise it will retrieve the color plus `no-repeat scroll` etc.

This works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Color Game</title>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  background-color: #232323;
 }

 h1 {
  color:#fff;
 }
 .square {
  width: 30%;
  background: purple;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
 }

 #container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Guess what color is<span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span>
<br/>
Click the box to know what color it is.
</h1>

<div id="container">
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
 <div class="square"> </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var colors = [
 "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
 "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
 "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
 "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
 ];

 var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
 var pickedColor = colors[1];
 var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

 colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

 for (var i=0; i<squares.length; i++){
  //add initial colors to square
  squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
  //add click listener to square
  squares[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
   var clickedColor = String(this.style.backgroundColor);
   alert(clickedColor);
   if (clickedColor === pickedColor){
    alert("Correct");
   } else{
    alert("Wrong");
   }
  });
 }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, It has something to do with the background. None repeat scroll is usually a property associated with the background. The above code commented by Andres should help you out. Good luck.